# Create a function that finds the points distanced r units by two lines

Tags: javascript, function, math

I have **two lines** defined **by two points** each(P1, P2, P3, P4).

I'd like to find the **2 points**(X0, Y0) that are **distanced r units** **from both lines**.

I found a way but I think it's too long to solve(too difficult for me) and maybe there's one shorter(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

my way:
[image: my solution]
Without solving it it's impossible tp create the function

I'd like to have the solution not the sistem.

Example(I'd like to find the **yellow points** knowing r):
[image]

Thanks.

(Sorry for my terrible english)

Comment: Are you trying to find the shortest (perpendicular) distance between two lines?

Comment: Are these 2-D or 3-D lines?

Comment: I strongly presume it's 2-D space since there is no `Z-Axis` @IsaacAbramowitz

Comment: Could you show a picture to make question more clear?

Comment: Draw on paper on in MSPaint of what you want to get

Comment: I think OP got lost in his brain trying to figure this out. **OP**, read the comments.

Comment: Are the lines parallel?

Comment: Yes, these are 2D lines

Comment: And these lines aren't parallel

Comment: Thanks. So you're given a point on the line, and you're trying to find the shortest distance from that point to the other line?

Comment: No, i have the two black lines defined by the points P1, P2, P3, P4. I'd like to find the two yellow points that are r units away from both the black lines

Comment: That's a much better explanation @strategaD :)

Comment: Are the green lines perpendicular to P-lines? @strategaD

Comment: yes, they are. Because they are distances

Comment: @strategaD In your first equation, you have `x0` & `y0`, I presume they are the yellow point coordinates?, correct?

Comment: yes, they are the yellow points coordinates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to isolate `x0` & `y0`? Have you found any other formulas for the same idea?

Comment: How do you know that those two yellow points are the ones that you want and not the two in the other sectors (there are a total of four points that satisfy your constraints)?

Comment: These equations are **not** too difficult to solve. By rearranging them you can arrive at a pair of simple linear equations in terms `x0` and `y0`, which can be solved with elementary school algebra.

Comment: However you should note that there can be up to 4 solutions (or infinitely many). To compute all of them, remove the absolute value operators and flip the signs of either equation.

Answer (score 1):

Variant A:
represent your lines in [general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_(or_standard)_form)

```
 a * x + b * y + c = 0
 d * x + e * y + f = 0
```

with normalized coefficients (divide equation by `Sqrt(a^2+b^2)`)

For this form point lies at distance r if

```
 |a * x + b * y + c| = r
 |d * x + e * y + f| = r
```

Open absolute value brackets with all possible +/- sign combinations and get 4 linear systems for 4 possible points

---

Variant B:

1) Find unit direction vectors of both lines `da` and `db`

2) Find intersection point `C` of two lines

3) Calculate angle between lines as

```
Fi = atan2(da.cross.db, da.dot.db)
```

4) Find unit bisector vector

```
b = (da + db).Normalized
```

5) Find perpendicular bisector

```
pb = (-b.y, b.x)
```

6) Get needed points as

```
C + b * r / Sin(Fi/2)
C - b * r / Sin(Fi/2)
C + pb * r / Cos(Fi/2)
C - pb * r / Cos(Fi/2)
```